# Using a subjunctive form correctly

Tags: subjunctive-mood

What are the differences between these sentences?

> 1) If I won the lottery, I would buy a house.
>
> 2) If I win a lottery, I will buy a house.
>
> 3) If I were to win a lottery, I would buy a house.
>
> 4) If I had won a lottery, I would have bought a house.

Answer (score 3):

All four sentences are grammatical.

1. Present conditional following *if clause*.
2. Future tense following *if clause*.
3. Subjunctive mood. present conditional following *if clause* in the subjunctive.
4. Past conditional following *if clause*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.How to identify as to where should we use present conditional,where to use subjunctive mood present conditional and where to use past conditional?Can you please elaborate the answer with an example?

Comment: Specifically when should we use the 3rd sentence?

Comment: The first and third really mean the same thing. It is just that the third employs more elegant language to say the same thing. number 2 deals with future circumstances, and number 4 what would have happened in the past.

Comment: @Anmol: You'd use your 3rd version if (a) - you want to use the subjunctive, and (b) - you're talking about either a "timeless irrealis" condition or a possible future lottery win. If (a) doesn't apply, you'd use your 1st or 2nd versions. If (b) doesn't apply, you might consider *"If I were to have won the lottery, I'd have bought a house"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now I'm totally confused, and just as I have to go out. I don't see how the 2nd version can be a substitute for the 1st. They don't mean the same thing. The 2nd is predicting some future circumstance. And I don't see how your final suggestion can possibly be a substitute for his 3rd version.

Comment: @WS2: I never actually said #1 and #2 mean the same (though in most credible contexts I can't see any real semantic difference). My final alternative was simply illustrating how the subjunctive could be used if winning the lottery ***wasn't*** *"either a 'timeless irrealis' condition or a possible future lottery win"* (i.e. - if it was a ***past*** condition that wasn't currently known to have obtained or not).

Comment: I came to know something about the sentences:

1) If I won the lottery, I would buy a house.(Used when chances of winning the lottery are very unlikely)

2) If I win a lottery, I will buy a house.(Used when chances of winning the lottery are very likely)

3) If I were to win a lottery, I would buy a house.(For future dreams of winning the lottery)

4) If I had won a lottery, I would have bought a house.(Past Conditional)

Please suggest me whether its correct or not

Comment: @FumbleFingers : Can you please explain when should we use the subjunctive mood?

Comment: @Anmol: I wouldn't normally use the subjunctive at all in your context - and I'm a native speaker "of a certain age" who does at least know *how* to use it. As you're presumably *not* a native speaker, my advice would be to ignore the subjunctive as often as possible.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If i were to use subjunctive form at all, then where would i use it?

Comment: @Anmol: You could (and indeed *did*) use it in your comment there! :) But you could have avoided it by something like *"If I [do] want to use the subjunctive, where can I use it?"* Of course, if you go for the easy option *("I don't want to use the subjunctive unless I can't avoid it")*, that particular question doesn't arise.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've just got in, having had a couple of pints. So I  shall not bend my mind to the subjunctive tonight. I may catch up with your comment tomorrow.

Comment: @WS2: I await your return with some trepidation (I suspect you're more clued up on subjunctive usages than me, so I can only hope my comment four above this survives your close attention! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Desperately busy installing new computer. Will catch up next week.